# shrink LVM (not XFS) to use for guest nodes (KVM)

Tags: centos7, lvm, xfs, shrink

I have /home`mountpoint (Type=LVM). how can I reduce`/home` from 418G to 200G and use remaining disk space for guest(KVM) Node? because XFS can not be shrunk ().

```
localhost home]$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1         259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2     259:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3     259:3    0 475.8G  0 part 
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0   418G  0 lvm  /home
```

/dev/mapper/centos-home xfs       418G   24G  394G   6% /home

Comment: What is the filesystem of `/home/`?

Comment: XFS     more details: /dev/mapper/centos-home xfs 418G 24G 394G 6% /home

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are out of luck. `XFS` can't be reduced directly. And as you do not have free space in LVM you can follow the next way:

1. Add new disk with size >24GB, 30 will be fine.
2. Partition this new disk, one partition is enough
3. Create filesystem on this partition
4. Mount this partition somewhere (not under `/home`!)
5. Login directly as root user and logout all other sessions
6. Stop any daemon which run from `/home`
7. Copy all the info from `/home` to the new filesystem
8. Unmount `/home`
9. Destroy `/home` LV
10. Create new LV (for `/home`). This time allocate only 30-40GB as you
     can extend it on the fly
11. Create filesystem on this LV
12. Mount this LV and make appropriate changes in /etc/fstab
13. Copy back all the information to this new LV.
14. Check all the coppied files and if all is OK unmount the partition
     from point 2 and remove this new disk

Comment: The 1st step states that "Add new disk with size >24GB, 30 will be fine."  Can the new disk can be external USB drive?

Comment: Yes, this disk is just a place for backup. If you used it before you can skip the steps 2 and 3. And will be wise not to use NTFS filesystem (for backup)

Comment: "Step 7: Copy all the info from /home to the new filesystem"  I am scared of. I have Oracle database install with many files on /home. I read few conversations/posts but none are complete explaining "cp -aR" OR "rsync" command . How do I be sure Copying all files including their names starting from . and ..  ; dependancies will copy absolutely everything and work after copying back to the new shrunk /home?  Thanks a lot Romeo.

Comment: For Oracle RDBMS will be much better to export the database and forget about the installation files (you can download and install it later). For copy you can use `cp -RP` to copy recursively and preserve permissions.

Comment: But why do not create dedicated directory in `/home` and then create softlink of this directory to the place where KVM keep disk files?